# Estimation of a series: why/where is my reasoning wrong'

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial, geometric-series, majorization

I have to give an estimation of the value of this series

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{3^n}{n!}$$

I know this series does converge to $e^3$, but I am not allowed to use this fact. Then here is what I thought of:

$$\dfrac{3^n}{n!} = \dfrac{\overbrace{3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdots 3}^{n \ \text{times}}}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n} = \dfrac{3\cdot 3\cdot 3}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}\cdot \dfrac{3\cdots 3}{\cdots n} = \dfrac{9}{2} \cdot \dfrac{3\cdot 3\cdots 3}{4\cdot 5\cdots n}$$

Now I majorized: $n! \geq 4^{n-3}$ hence $\frac{1}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{4^{n-3}}$ so then

$$\dfrac{3^n}{n!} \leq \dfrac{9}{2}\cdot \dfrac{3^{n-3}}{4^{n-3}}$$

So then

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{3^n}{n!} \leq \dfrac{9}{2}\cdot \dfrac{64}{27}\sum_{n = 3}^{+\infty} \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n$$

Using the geometric progression and substracting the exceeding terms:

$$\sum_{n= 3}^{+\infty} = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} -\  \text{term of n = 0}\ - \ \text{term of n = 1}\ - \ \text{term of n = 2}$$

I got

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{3^n}{n!} \leq 18$$

Now this is wrong for $e^3 \approx 20.08$. Where did I went wrong?

Comment: You need to compare geometric sum starting from $3$ with the original series starting from $3$. So $e^3-1-3-9/2 < 18$ is true.

Comment: @Riemann Would it be correct the same if I compared the initial series with the geometric series from zero? I mean 

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{3^n}{n!} \leq \frac{9}{2}\cdot \frac{64}{27} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$

Comment: Then it is not necessarily true, since your inequality for each term may not no longer hold.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$\sum_{n = {\color{red}3}}^{+\infty} \dfrac{3^n}{n!} \leq \dfrac{9}{2}\cdot \dfrac{64}{27}\sum_{n = 3}^{+\infty} \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n=18$$
and so
$$\sum_{n = {\color{red}0}}^{+\infty} \dfrac{3^n}{n!} \leq \frac{17}2+18=26.5.$$

Comment: Would it be the same if I compared the initial series with the geometric series from zero? I mean like

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{3^n}{n!} \leq \dfrac{9}{2}\cdot \dfrac{64}{27}\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$

or would it be wrong?